# Frontier exploration in ROS noetic

Tags: ros

I want to use frontier explanation in Ros noetic.
http://wiki.ros.org/frontier_exploration
Is there a way to use in this Ros package?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the developer [doesn't have time to update it and is looking for volunteers.](https://github.com/paulbovbel/frontier_exploration/issues/55#issuecomment-672152262)

It might not be a terrible amount of work to do it yourself.  Usually it involves:

1. Cloning the repo and updating the dependencies for Noetic.
2. Compiling it yourself and fixing the errors.
3. Testing it.
4. Once it's good, making a pull request, so other people can use it.